# Multi-touch support for web browsers/web pages

Tags: multi-touch

Multi-touch seems to be gathering more and more references worldwide every day. Soon the prices will most likely drop, as there are already a good amount of companies investing in them. Now what I wanted to ask to stackoverflow is the following:

- Is it time to start developing an open-source multi-touch api for browsers, like addons to Firefox?
- What modifications will we need to do to current web-frameworks to support for multi-touch?

I know this is not directly programming related, thus being community wiki. Just trying to gathering some opinions on it.

Edit: What i'm trying to aim with this is to know if devs would be interested in this, a couple of stuff you could probably do would be like:

- Zooming
- Increased iteractivity, for example allowing re-organization of the webpage
- Multiple persons using the same web-page at the same time.

Why the question (one example):
 - Javascript, for example, is not ready to handle multiple actions at the same time. (You can simulate it, but you can't just go to your web-browser with 2 mouse pointers and do multiple stuff at the same time)

Comment: prima facie, I'm not sure in what way JS couldn't support multi-touch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 3.1 already supports multitouch gestures.

Comment: really? ok didn't knew that :x

Comment: So does IE9. And Sencha Touch is an existing javascript framework that has (reasonable) multi browser support.

Comment: is this answer for mobile devices? Because Firefox does not officialy support multi-touch in desktop browsers as of now.